# jQuery script only working if it's above a function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, laravel

I am using Bootstrap as my template, and Laravel as my framework. As suggested within the examples, you should load your jQuery script at the bottom of the page - to speed up the loading.

Within my application, I have this function that checks if an alert exists in the session, and if so, show it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    toastr.options = {
        "closeButton": false
    };
    toastr. {
        {
            Session::get('flash_notification.level')
        }
    }('{{ Session::get('
        flash_notification.message ') }}')
});
```

This is shown above where I load the jQuery script:

```
@if (Session::has('flash_notification.message'))

    <script>

    The above script is loaded here.

    </script>

@endif

    @yield('content')

</div>

<!-- Scripts -->
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

In order to get this working, I need to declare my jQuery file in the header of the template, but I know this isn't best practice. I initially thought that by using the `$(document).ready()` method, it would resolve this, but it doesn't.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It is best to put the script calls in the footer so they are loaded last. This means that any other JS you write will need to be below them. You could add your other JS to another file which is included after the jQuery load.

If you cannot, you could add it to the header and add the `defer` attribute to the `script` tag to defer it's loading.

Option 1 should be preferred though.